# Airbnb react-dates returns null

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

This is code that I implemented

```html
<DayPickerRangeController
                startDate={startDate}
                startDateId="startDateId"
                endDate={endDate}
                endDateId="endDateId"
                onDatesChange={(date) => console.log(date)}
                focusedInput={focus}
                onFocusChange={(focus) => console.log(focus)}
              />
```

But onDatesChange returns null

```
{startDate: null, endDate: null}
```

here are my hooks

```js
const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState({
    startDate: null,
    endDate: null,
  });
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(null);

const { startDate, endDate } = dateRange;
```

Any ideas why?

These are my imports

```js
import 'react-dates/initialize';
import { DayPickerRangeController } from 'react-dates';
```

here is full code

```js
import 'react-dates/initialize';
import { DayPickerRangeController } from 'react-dates';

const DatePicker = ({ name, items, handler }) => {

  const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState({
    startDate: null,
    endDate: null,
  });

  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(null);
  const { startDate, endDate } = dateRange;

  return (
    <DayPickerRangeController
       startDate={startDate}
       startDateId="startDateId"
       endDate={endDate}
       endDateId="endDateId"
       onDatesChange={(date) => console.log(date)}
       focusedInput={focus}
       onFocusChange={(focus) => console.log(focus)}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Full code or online demo would be better for others to catch up with the problem you are facing

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested it in codesandbox and it seems that `onFocusChange` is not getting triggered once the `focus` variable ends up being null.

Use constants, as described in react-dates [docs](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates#daypickerrangecontroller), not `null`.

```
const [focus, setFocus] = useState(START_DATE);
...
focusedInput={this.state.focusedInput} // PropTypes.oneOf([START_DATE, END_DATE]) or null,
```

`START_DATE, END_DATE` constants can be easily imported:

```
import { START_DATE, END_DATE } from 'react-dates/constants';
```

**Ps:** when you are done with selecting the range, `focus` variable will be given `null` value again. In order to pick the values again, I guess it would be the best to reset all the values (`focus`, `startDate` and `endDate`)

**Update:**

I've checked their implementation [here](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates/blob/480b9902d69e64e62a2ef5c2d3b5fc3adef94444/examples/DayPickerRangeControllerWrapper.jsx#L143).
It's pretty straight forward:

```
onFocusChange={(f) => {
        setFocus(!f ? START_DATE : f);
       }}
```

Comment: that's it. I just still can't figure out how to edit dates. I set everything back to null and I still can't edit them

Comment: did you reset `focus` to be `START_DATE` again?

Comment: Okay. Now I did. Bur problem is that it takes two clicks to change to new date. Could this be default behaviour or..

Comment: You're right, I doubt it as well. Though, I have used `DayPickerRange` for some time and never had an issue like this.

Comment: ah well.. never mind.. thank you for your help. You saved me :)

Comment: I wish I can upvote you again :D. Thank you a lot. It works

Comment: No worries. Sretno! :D

Comment: Hvala puno. Takodje